# Character encoding from MySQL to CSV using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I am having problem with special character e.g. Russian characters are converted into `????` when I export MySQL query to CSV file.I used `iconv()` function but it is not working. 
What should I do to fix this issue. I read different posts but nothing seems to be working for me

```
public function  generateReport($nameReport,$db,$query,$host,$user,$pwd){

        $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd);
        if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $con);

        if (!$db_selected)
        {
            die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysql_error());
        }

        $res = mysql_query($query);


        if (!$res) {
            $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
            $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
            die($message);
        }

        $file='/home/'.$nameReport.'.csv';


        $fp = fopen($file,'w') or exit("Unable to open file!");


    if($fp){    

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        $line = "";
        $comma = "";
        foreach($row as $name => $value) {
            $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $line .= "\n";
        fputs($fp, $line);

            mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

            $line = "";
            $comma = "";
            foreach($row as $value) {
                iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $value ), 'UTF-8', $value);
                $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
                $comma = ",";
            }
            $line .= "\n";
            fputs($fp, $line);

        }

    }

        return '/home/'.$nameReport.'.csv';

            }
```

Comment: Is this part of a legacy application? I really hope you're not writing new code with the wickedly out of date `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: Its just wrote a function for re usability . If you have better suggestion I can change it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a function. What I'm saying is `mysql_query` is a deprecated interface, it's being removed from PHP, so you should avoid using it whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not export directly from MySQL to CSV without going through PHP?

```
SELECT field_you_want, other_field_you_want 
FROM your_table
INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\filename.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: I need to send this report via email so I have to use PHP

Comment: If you're using PHP to send the email, you can still execute the MySQL query to build the CSV. Just have the function you pass your select query to append the CSV creation part. Something like `$query .= "INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\filename.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"`

Comment: Dumping temporary files in the root of your drive is pretty sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

for russian only, you can try this

```
$value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'KOI8-R','UTF-8' );
$line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
$comma = ",";
```

for other charsets, you have to find a way to get the charset info.
maybe, mb_detect_encoding with mb_detect_order
or maybe if you get that text from a website: from server header or charset defined at the head of page...